# Cannot Build in Webpack without odd error

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm using Webpack to build a very simple, small tutorial with ReactJS and JSX code.  I'm getting an error I don't understand.

```
Hash: 3646b1c9ad32c77ed791
Version: webpack 4.29.3
Time: 492ms
Built at: 02/14/2019 8:24:59 AM
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] ./src/index.js 223 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.js 6:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     render() {
|         return (
>             <h1>Hello world!</h1>
|         )
|     }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! react@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely             
additional logging output above.
```

My index.js file has only this:

```
import React from 'react';
class HelloThere extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <HelloThere/>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Can anyone suggest why the Webpack build is showing an error?

**EDIT:**
my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "react projects",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "John Doe",
  "license": "ISC",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "./dist/main.js"
    }
};
```

Help sorting this out would be greatly appreciated.  It's probably a simple problem.

Comment: Show us your webpack config :)

Comment: You need to use `babel-loader` with the `@babel/preset-react`

Comment: I added my config info above.  Thanks for looking at this.